# How to read data set without line break in java

Tags: java, string, spring-batch

I have a dataset like the following,

```
chris~88~alex~23~nivya~34~simon~33...........
```

this data represents the name and the age of some people. How I can capture each of their name and age into a pojo and save in DB. I need to know how we can use stringutils to get their name and age out of this large string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply by using split method from `String` class. Split by character `~`, which will return `array` of `string`. Where even index values will be name and odd number values will be age. Then you can `map` that to object of pojo class and create list.

**Code to convert String to POJO of name and age:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "chris~88~alex~23~nivya~34~simon~33";
    String[] nameAge = a.split("~");

    List<Person> persons = IntStream.range(0, nameAge.length).filter(x -> x % 2 == 0)
        .mapToObj(i -> new Person(nameAge[i], Integer.valueOf(nameAge[i + 1]))).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(persons);
  }
```

**POJO :**

```
class Person {

  String name;

  int age;

  public Person(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Person [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gaurav! This exactly solve my issue!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what specific DB you are using, but here is a possible way to split the dataset with a regex:

```
String dataset = "chris~88~alex~23~nivya~34~simon~33~tim~34~berta~12~jon~55";
String[] splitDataset = dataset.split("~");
```

`splitDataset` now contains for all even the `i` the name and for all uneven indices the respective age (`i+1`).

Comment: Thanks Marcello!